# REACT GET requiest getting base url twice

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, axios

Using REACT front-end with Django back-end. When i call request api i can see it being pulled correctly, however when onClick is called i get a 404 `XHRGEThttp://localhost:3000/http//127.0.0.1:8000/undefined` so it seems that i am somehow calling the base url twice but i am not sure how?

here is my main component file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import SubtagsList from './list_subtags';
import axios from 'axios';

class TagsList extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            tagData: [],
            subtags: " ",
            showComponent: false,
        }
    this.getSubtagDetail = this.getSubtagDetail.bind(this);
    this.showSubtags = this.showSubtags.bind(this);
    }

    getSubtagDetail(item){
        axios.get("http//127.0.0.1:8000/".concat(item.absolute_url))
        .then((response) =>{
            this.setState({subtags: response.data})
        })
        .catch(function(error){
            console.log(error);
        })
    }

    showSubtags(item){
        this.getSubtagDetail(item);
        this.setState({showComponent: true})
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/")
        .then( (response) => {
         this.setState({tagData: response.data})
        })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
     })
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.tagData.map((item) => {
                    return (
                        <h3 key={item.id} onClick={() => this.showSubtags(item)}>
                            {item.tag_name}
                        </h3>
                    );
                })}
                {this.state.showComponent ? (
                    <SubtagsList subtagDetail={this.state.subtags} />
                ) : null}
            </div>
        )
    }
}


export default TagsList;
```

here is the api response:

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "tag_name": "IT/Computer Issues",
        "type": "Tag"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "subtag_name": "Website",
        "absolute_url": "/1",
        "type": "SubTag"
    }
]
```

and this is the `SubtagsList` component imported:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class SubtagsList extends Component {

    render() {
        const obj = this.props.subtagDetail;
        return (
            <div style={{ color: "yellow", border: "1px solid yellow" }}>
                <p>{obj.subtag_name}</p>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default SubtagsList;
```

Can anyone shed some light on what i might be doing wrong here?

Comment: You're missing a colon after `http` in the url in the `getSubtagDetail` function: `"http://127.0.0.1:8000/"`

Comment: wow! thanks @iain-shelvington always the smallest thing - this solves the double base URL - it still seems to be returning undefined on subtag_name but i am guessing that is a whole new issue now